# Issue displaying an image tkinter

Tags: tkinter, button

I would like to open an image when clicking a button with tkinter.
According to the button, the image which is displayed is changing.
So, the name of the button is the name of a dish and when the user click on it, it displays the image corresponding to the dish. (I'm taking the name of the dish from a database).

This is my code:

```py
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

class Application(tk.Frame):
    x = 2
    def __init__(self, param = None, i = None, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        if (self.x == 2):
            param = "coucou"
        self.hi_there = tk.Label(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = param
        #self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

        # Opening file in read format
        File = open('data.txt',"r")
        if(File == None):
            print("File Not Found..")
        else:
            while(True):
                # extracting data from records 
                record = File.readline()
                if (record == ''): break
                data = record.split(',')
                print('Name of the dish:', data[0])
                self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
                self.hi_there["text"] = data[0]
                self.hi_there["command"] = self.photoOfTheDish
                self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
                # printing each record's data in organised form
                for i in range(1, len(data)):
                    print('Ingredients:',data[i])
                    self.hi_there = tk.Label(self)
                    self.hi_there["text"] = data[i]
                    self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
        File.close()

    def photoOfTheDish(self):
        #i = "0.ppm"
        novi = Toplevel()
        canvas = Canvas(novi, width = 1500, height = 1000)
        canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
        with open('data.txt') as f:
            count = sum(1 for _ in f)
        print(count)
        for i in range(count):
            print(i)
            gif1 = PhotoImage(file = str(i) + ".ppm")
                                        #image not visual
            canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
            #assigned the gif1 to the canvas object
            canvas.gif1 = gif1


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("5000x2000")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

The important part of my code for this issue is here:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
        count = sum(1 for _ in f)
    print(count)
    for i in range(count):
        print(i)
        gif1 = PhotoImage(file = str(i) + ".ppm")
                                    #image not visual
        canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
        #assigned the gif1 to the canvas object
        canvas.gif1 = gif1
```

So I want to open images named "0.ppm", "1.ppm", "2.ppm"... that is why I created a counter so I have "i.ppm" with i going from 0 to the number of lines in my database.

My problem is: when I click on a button, the image displayed is not the image of the selected dish, it's always the image of the last dish because i is going straight away to the final number of lines. But I want it to display the right image according to the right dish.

Comment: You tried solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) problem but `canvas` goes out of scope so it's deleted by python's garbage collector. When that happens it also deletes the `PhotoImage`. Put the canvas in a variable named `self.canvas`

Comment: I put `self.` in front of all my canvas but it's doing the same...

Comment: And actually I think with my code, the image is not linked to the clicked button. Do you know how I can manage that? Like sharing the variables between the functions to say when I click on the first button the image "0.ppm" should be displayed, when I click on the fifth one the image "4.ppm" etc...